# How to hit Web Service Based on WSDL

Tags: c#, azure

Here is the WSDL

http://cc93161263da499cb8f0e0e0b2bcc5a9.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc?wsdl

How can I get to the GetHello service

I tried

http://cc93161263da499cb8f0e0e0b2bcc5a9.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc/GetHello

But I receive a bad request error....

Any thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to use VS to generate a client proxy based on the WSDL (Add a Service Reference to your project).

Regarding the error: it could be because you're not passing in an input parameter... looks like there is a blank sequence.  Or that your browser is sending in accepts parameters that don't match what the server expects (soap).

See this for command line generation without VS:

http://cc93161263da499cb8f0e0e0b2bcc5a9.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc?help